# Is it good to use fixnums as keys in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, key, symbols, fixnum

I'm creating a hash to represent a few of the records in a MySQL database. The hash keys corresponds to the database ID fields and the hash values correspond to the database name fields.

What's better & why?

1. Array

   This works, but Ruby seems inefficient with sparse arrays because it appears that there's the extra overhead of setting the values of all intermediary indexes tp `nil`.

   ```
   fruits = []
   fruits[23] = "apple"
   fruits[109] = "orange"
   # ...
   fruits[23429] = "banana"
   ```
2. Hash with fixnum as keys

   I like this the best, but I've always read it's best to use symbols as keys in a hash. Is it equally as good to use fixnums as keys in a hash? I'm not sure if it is, but I think `34.hash` because of the nature of fixnums, i.e., `34.equal? 34` is true whereas `"hi".equal? "hi"` is false.

   ```
   fruits = {
     23 => "apple",
     109 => "orange",
     # ...
     23429 => "banana"
   }
   ```
3. Hash with interned string representations of fixnums as keys

   By converting the fixnums to strings and then symbols, I'm able to use symbols as keys. This conversion, however, is annoying, and someone once told me that interning strings is inefficient. Is that so? They just look ugly to me.

   ```
   fruits = {
     :"23" => "apple",
     :"109" => "orange",
     # ...
     :"23429" => "banana"
   }
   ```
4. Hash with symbols as keys

   I can get prettier symbols (and also use the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax) by prefixing each key with an alpha character, but then, this solution also requires conversion.

   ```
   fruits = {
     i23: "apple",
     i109: "orange",
     # ...
     i23429: "banana"
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning behind only using symbols as keys for a hash. Do you have any links that give a good explanation why that maybe the case?

Comment: This [blog post on understanding Ruby symbols](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols) gives a good explanation of why & when to use symbols over strings. And this [blog post recommends a ruby symbol as an excellent choice for a hash key](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol#9). But, what about fixnums? Aren't they equally good as symbols to use as hash keys? I posit that they are.

Comment: Thanks, if the main problem that symbols solve in hashes is memory management, then I think @DigitalRoss has it 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the reasoning is that `symbol.hash` is constant so calling `hash` on a symbol is a simple property lookup and quite fast; symbols are optimized for this particular use. The hash value for a string needs to be computed so calling `hash` on a string involves real work and strings don't appear to cache their hash values. The `hash` value for a Fixnum appears to be computed with some simple bit mangling on the Fixnum's internal object ID (a constant) so it should also be quick. Don't take any of this as authoritative, I just did a quick review of the 1.9.2 source but I'm hardly an expert on the Ruby internals.

That said, I'd use Fixnums as hash keys. That gives you a natural representation for a sparse array that is also efficient in terms of memory. Any speed differences will probably be irrelevant noise. So, go with the clearest approach and worry about optimization when there is a real speed problem.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion: use a `Hash` with `Fixnum` keys.

As you say, this will allow a sparse object. There are special speed and memory optimizations that apply to `Fixnum`s. They compare as expected and convert to everything. It should be faster and simpler than symbols and you won't have the strangeness of interning strings that couldn't ordinarily have been parsed.